# Explain why alumina-containing zeolites possess chemically active surfaces

Tags: homework, kinetics, catalysis, surface-chemistry

I think zeolites possess acid sites that are catalytically active in many hydrocarbon reactions. The pore system only allows molecules that are small enough to enter, hence it affects the selectivity of reactions by excluding both the participation and formation of molecules that are too large for the pores. Is that right or not ?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry! This seems like a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We ‎have a policy which states that you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the ‎problem. It'll make us certain that we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this ‎question may get closed.

Answer (score 2):

Alumina containing zeolites have composition that can be represented as

[image]

where M is metal ion with m charge, and so on, respectively. 
Meaning you have $[SiO_4]^{4-}$ and $[AlO_4]^{5-}$ tetrahedra which make up negatively charged framework. Positive ions compensate for this negative charge. There is a rule from 1954. called Löwenstein rule, which states that x/y has to be less than 1, which in turn implies there are no Al-O-Al bonds, as two tetrahedra have Al atoms in their tetrahedral positions. This gives really great internal specific area and resistance to high temperature, which makes this type of zeolite a great candidate for catalysis (heterogenous).
The following picture nicely represents the active sites in zeolites - they act as molecular sieves, as only the specific molecules fit in the pores:[image]